# Update NPM Packages

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I seem to understand how to clone a repository, but I'm not sure I'm fully grasping how to keep that repository current with what's on Github. I'm using [Basscss](https://github.com/jxnblk/basscss) for example, and I believe my local project is slightly out of date with what's on Github.

I'm trying to update Basscss to the latest version using `npm update`but even after running that command my `package.json` file remains the same with the version stuck at "4.2.1".

```
"name": "basscss",
"version": "4.2.1",
...
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `npm list` say is installed

Answer (score 0):

`npm update` will update the module's files listed in your project. if you want to update your package.json file with the newer version. use the save option.

`npm update --save`

---

*edit*

`npm install basscss@latest --save`

I would try to re-install latest and save to package file. BTW, your package.json should reference the dep's like this:

```
"name" : "YOUR_PROJECT",
"version" : "0.0.1",
"dependencies": {
  "basscss": "^4.2.4",
}
```

Comment: The current version of "basscss-base-buttons" is "^1.0.3" and my version in my `package.json` file is listed as "^1.0.0". When I run `npm update basscss-base-buttons --save` the `package.json` file remains as "^1.0.0". No idea why this happening...

Comment: @realph what does `npm list` say the version of the basscss is?